# pandas str.contains match exact substring not working with regex boudry

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes, and trying to find out a way to match the exact substring from one dataframe to another dataframe.

**First DataFrame**:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

random_data = {'Place Name':['TS~HOT_MD~h_PB~progra_VV~gogl', 'FM~uiosv_PB~emo_SZ~1x1_TG~bhv'], 
              'Site':['DV360', 'Adikteev']}
        
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(random_data)
print(dataframe)
```

**Second DataFrame**

```py
test_data = {'code name': ['PB', 'PB', 'PB'], 
             'Actual':['programmatic me', 'emoteev', 'programmatic-mechanics'],
             'code':['progra', 'emo', 'prog']}

test_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
```

**Approach**

```py
for k, l, m in zip(test_dataframe.iloc[:, 0], test_dataframe.iloc[:, 1], test_dataframe.iloc[:, 2]):
    dataframe['Site'] = np.select([dataframe['Place Name'].str.contains(r'\b{}~{}\b'.format(k, m), regex=False)], [l],
                                  default=dataframe['Site'])
```

The current output is as below, though I am expecting to match the exact substring, which is not working with the code above.

Current Output:

```py
Place Name                        Site
TS~HOT_MD~h_PB~progra_VV~gogl     programmatic-mechanics
FM~uiosv_PB~emo_SZ~1x1_TG~bhv     emoteev
```

Expected Output:

```py
Place Name                        Site
TS~HOT_MD~h_PB~progra_VV~gogl     programmatic me
FM~uiosv_PB~emo_SZ~1x1_TG~bhv     emoteev
```

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 random_data = {'Place Name':['TS~HOT_MD~h_PB~progra_VV~gogl',
                                     'FM~uiosv_PB~emo_SZ~1x1_TG~bhv'], 'Site':['DV360', 'Adikteev']}
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(random_data)

    test_data = {'code name': ['PB', 'PB', 'PB'], 'Actual':['programmatic me', 'emoteev', 'programmatic-mechanics'],
                 'code':['progra', 'emo', 'prog']}
    test_dataframe  = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
```

Map the `test_datframe` `code` and `Actual` into dictionary as `key` and `value` respectively

```
keys=test_dataframe['code'].values.tolist()

dicto=dict(zip(test_dataframe.code, test_dataframe.Actual))
dicto
```

Join the keys separated by [|](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regex-cheatsheet/) to enable search of either phrases

```
k = '|'.join(r"{}".format(x) for x in dicto.keys())
k
```

Extract string from datframe meeting any of the phrases in k and map them to to the dictionary

```
dataframe['Site'] = dataframe['Place Name'].str.extract('('+ k + ')', expand=False).map(dicto)
dataframe
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I am getting error, AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: What version of pandas are you running. I have run it on 2 machines, one with 0.25 and the other with 1.0.1. All good. See appended screen shot in my answer

Comment: import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.0.3'

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to copy keys=test_dataframe['code'].values.tolist()
 in the answer sent

Comment: @MishD how did you go?

Comment: Just give me some time for checking.

Comment: Still, no luck, same error, why does word boundary not working in my original post.

Comment: Try match using word boundary. Edit r"{}" to r"\b{}\b" so that you have k = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in dicto.keys())

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but this does the trick.

#### Set up data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
random_data = {'Place Name':['TS~HOT_MD~h_PB~progra_VV~gogl',
                                'FM~uiosv_PB~emo_SZ~1x1_TG~bhv'], 'Site':['DV360', 'Adikteev']}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(random_data)

test_data = {'code name': ['PB', 'PB', 'PB'], 'Actual':['programmatic me', 'emoteev', 'programmatic-mechanics'],
             'code':['progra', 'emo', 'prog']}

test_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
```

#### Solution

Create a column in `test_dataframe` with the substring to match:

```
test_dataframe['match_str'] = test_dataframe['code name'] + '~' + test_dataframe.code

print(test_dataframe)
```

```
  code name                  Actual    code  match_str
0        PB         programmatic me  progra  PB~progra
1        PB                 emoteev     emo     PB~emo
2        PB  programmatic-mechanics    prog    PB~prog
```

Define a function to apply to `test_dataframe`:

```
def match_string(row, dataframe):
    ind = row.name
    try:
        if row[-1] in dataframe.loc[ind, 'Place Name']:
            return row[1]
        else:
            return dataframe.loc[ind, 'Site']
    except KeyError:
        # More rows in test_dataframe than there are in dataframe
        pass

# Apply match_string and assign back to dataframe
dataframe['Site'] = test_dataframe.apply(match_string, args=(dataframe,), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                      Place Name             Site
0  TS~HOT_MD~h_PB~progra_VV~gogl  programmatic me
1  FM~uiosv_PB~emo_SZ~1x1_TG~bhv          emoteev
```

Comment: Is there a way by using regex pattern the same way using NumPy, pandas?

Comment: Yes, `pandas` has various regex methods, e.g. `str.match` and `str.contains` which correspond to `re.match` and `re.search` respectively.

Comment: str.contains seems not working. trying with str.match.

Comment: However, the 'solution' I've posted doesn't give your desired result (yet).  As far as I can tell, I've recreated your desired logic (which I may have misunderstood), and I've used the data you supplied (thanks for that!)  So I'm unsure why I'm getting `emoteev` in the second row of the output.  Once that's sorted, I'll understand the logic of the question fully and can better help with modifying the answer to use regex.

Comment: If `str.contains` doesn't work, then `str.match` won't, as the latter is just a stricter version or the former (i.e. it only looks for patterns at the start of the string instead of throughout).

Comment: so for emoteev thing its correct at your code. i see mine was type and i am editing the question. I just need to use regex way(the way i posted) since i have already written the logic depends on so many variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211131/discussion-between-mishd-and-chris).

Comment: See my attempt. Let me know if it does you good. Else can find other ways to help.